# JMeter UI scheduler force start/end date values

Tags: jmeter

According to [docs](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group) I can use JMeter Thread scheduler with Duration and/or Startup Delay which override End time and Start time respectively.

> You can configure Duration (seconds) and Startup Delay (seconds) to
>   control the duration of each thread group and the after how much
>   seconds it starts. When the test is started, JMeter will wait Startup
>   Delay (seconds) before starting the Threads of the Thread Group and
>   run for the configured Duration (seconds) time. Note those 2 options
>   override the Start time and End time.
>
> Alternatively (although not recommended as not very flexible) you can
>   use the two other fields Start time and End time.

But in JMeter UI I can't delete Start time and End time, because if I delete its values it return with current time although irrelevant.

Before
[image]
After:
[image]
Is it a bug or there's a reason for that behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define Duration and Startup delay, they override Start Time and End Time.

The latter options should be avoided and in upcoming JMeter 3.4, the 2 fields have been removed.

See:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61549

Comment: Thanks, BTW should it mark as deprecated in changes? I didn't find any deprecation notes in JMeter 3.3

Comment: Yes it should have been. Maybe we'll do that in an update soon.